# Can't make the headlessui dropdown to open on mouse hover and not on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-ui, headless-ui

I build an app in React and I have this dropdown from Tailwind UI which is opened on click events and I want to make it open on mouse hover too.

```
<Menu as="div" className="relative inline-block text-left ">
    <div>
      <Menu.Button className="inline-flex w-full justify-center rounded-md bg-white px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-offset-gray-100">
        Features
        <ChevronDownIcon
          className="-mr-1 ml- h-5 w-5"
          aria-hidden="true"
        />
      </Menu.Button>
    </div>

    <Transition
      as={Fragment}
      enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
      enterFrom="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
      enterTo="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
      leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
      leaveFrom="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
      leaveTo="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
    >
      <Menu.Items className="absolute left-0 z-10 mt-2 w-56 origin-top-right rounded-md bg-white shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none">
        <div className="py-1">
          <Menu.Item>
            {({ active }) => (
              <Link
                to="#"
                className={classNames(
                  active ? "bg-primary-light-bk text-gray-900" : "text-gray-500",
                  "block px-4 py-2 text-sm"
                )}
              >
                Feature 1
              </Link>
            )}
          </Menu.Item>
          <Menu.Item>
            {({ active }) => (
              <Link
                to="#"
                className={classNames(
                  active ? "bg-primary-light-bk text-gray-900" : "text-gray-500",
                  "block px-4 py-2 text-sm"
                )}
              >
                Feature 2
              </Link>
            )}
          </Menu.Item>
        </div>
      </Menu.Items>
    </Transition>
  </Menu>
```

What should I change?

Comment: One option here is to use `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave`. Are you looking for a solution that doesn't involve any additional state updates?

Comment: I'm looking for any kind of solution. Can you tell me how should I resolve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to add onMouseEnter event to your Menu.Button and use handler for this event.
Get argument **event** and then use event.target in handler or { target } and then use just **target**. then use .click() method that simulates a mouse click on the **target** element.

When you hover over Menu.Button onMouseEnter has triggered and .click method fires the element's click event. Menu is opened.

```
<Menu.Button onMouseEnter={({target})=> target.click()} className="...">
    Features
    <ChevronDownIcon
      className="-mr-1 ml- h-5 w-5"
      aria-hidden="true"
    />
  </Menu.Button>
```

If you try this you'll see that when you hover the menu.button two times - menu's opened then closed. That because .click() method fires two times.
You can use "open" state. Wrap all of your code inside Menu

`{({ open }) => (your code)}`

And add
`onMouseEnter={({target})=> open ? "" : target.click()}`.
"open" is boolean. True when menu is opened, no need to trigger click event and close it. When "open" is false we'll use our target.click() method!

```
<Menu as="div" className="relative inline-block text-left ">
  {({open}) => (
    <div>
     <div>
      <Menu.Button onMouseEnter={({target})=> open ? "" : target.click()} className="inline-flex w-full justify-center rounded-md bg-white px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-offset-gray-100">
        Features
        <ChevronDownIcon
          className="-mr-1 ml- h-5 w-5"
          aria-hidden="true"
        />
      </Menu.Button>
    </div>
   ... your code ...
  </div>
  )}
</Menu>
```

Comment: how would this work with typescript?

Comment: @CalebEverett something like this `(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => open ? "" : event.currentTarget.click()`

Comment: Menu is not closing...https://codesandbox.io/s/headlessui-menu-forked-y5q9hm?file=/src/App.js