# Hover on headlessui Menu element to open instead of click

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, headless-ui

I am trying to create a Navbar using [headlessui’s Menu](https://headlessui.com/react/menu) component. Since hovering is not supported by the component itself, I went through the GitHub issue thread and tried some solutions there. Yet, none of them seems to work without glitching: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/headlessui/issues/239

I build a minimal demo of my navbar (containing nested and untested (direct) links):
https://codesandbox.io/s/headlessui-menu-forked-y5q9hm?file=/src/App.js

In here I added `onMouseEnter` suggested from this SO: [Can't make the headlessui dropdown to open on mouse hover and not on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74680408/cant-make-the-headlessui-dropdown-to-open-on-mouse-hover-and-not-on-click)

Yet, it fails to close the menus...

Is there a solution out there?

UPDATE:
Naivly, I added an `onMouseLeave` block and swapped the ternary condition. This seem to work in the first place, yet, the page crashes when switching between two menu items being nested:
https://codesandbox.io/s/headlessui-menu-forked-ctfvjm?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are nearly there - the only problem remaining in the updated codesandbox seems to be an exception that is raised when `onMouseLeave` is triggered on the SVG graphics element inside the menu item, which can not react to `click` events.

The easiest way to fix it is to make the `click` call null-safe by using use the optional chaining operator:

```
onMouseEnter={({ target }) => open ? "" : target.click?.()}
onMouseLeave={({ target }) => open ? target.click?.() : ""}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you're handling the `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` events to control the menu opening and closing. However, the issue arises when rapidly moving between nested items.

One potential approach to resolve this issue is by introducing a delay in closing the menu on mouse leave. This could prevent accidental closure when moving between menu items.

something like:

```
  const openMenu = () => {
    setIsOpen(true);
    if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
  };

  const closeMenu = () => {
    setTimer(setTimeout(() => setIsOpen(false), 200));
  };

 return (


        <div
          onMouseEnter={openMenu}
          onMouseLeave={closeMenu}
          className={`${
            active ? 'bg-blue-500 text-white' : 'bg-white text-black'
          } cursor-pointer p-2`}
        >
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to move the `onMouseLeave` event to the parent element if you want users to be able to interact with the submenu, otherwise it will close when moving out of the button to click on a link.

I haven't tested this but it may also help to address the issue of the event failing to close the submenu.

However in practice I tent to avoid using mouse events for hover interactions where possible.

You could solve this with css:

First you would need to remove the condition for rendering the menu items.

Then hide them by default and show them when the button or submenu itself are hovered over.

```
li > ul[id*=ui-menu-items] {
    display: none;
}

li > button:hover + ul[id*=ui-menu-items],
ul[id*=ui-menu-items]:hover {
    display: block;
}
```